# JButton invoked JTable show up in delay

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm writing a library system that interacts with database currently. 
The function I want is: each time I click the JButton "lobBut", the JTable "table" will show the newest content. 
Using the following code, I can realize this function. HOWEVER, there is a delay in the showing up of the JTable. To make things weirder, If I click on other applications (such as Chrome or any other), the JTable would show up immediately without delay. Could anyone help me overcome this issue? Thank you!

```
JButton lobBut = new JButton("List of Books");
lobBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            centerPanel.removeAll();
            JTable bookTable = new JTable(BookTableModel.getTableModel("SELECT * FROM books"));
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(bookTable);
            bookTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 70));
            bookTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) bookTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
            renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            bookTable.setShowGrid(true);
            bookTable.setGridColor(Color.GREEN);
            bookTable.setVisible(true);
            centerPanel.add(pane);
        }
    });
```

Here is the BookTableModel class:

```
public class BookTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
private String[] columnNames = {};
private Object[][] data = {};

public int getColumnCount(){
    return columnNames.length;
}

public int getRowCount(){
    return data.length;
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
    return data[row][col];
}

public String getColumnName(int col){
    return columnNames[col];
}

public Class getColumnClass(int c){
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
}

public static DefaultTableModel getTableModel(String sql){
    try(
            Statement stmt = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ){
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for(int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++){
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while(rs.next()){
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for(int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++){
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);


    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.print(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
    centerPanel.updateUI();
```

after

```
    centerPanel.add(pane);
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to marry you!

Comment: This is not a an appropriate use of `updateUI()`; instead, implement  `validate()` the enclosing container.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more point in addition to georgechen answer.
In your code, I noticed that, a new jtable is getting created every time you clicks the button.

Instead, try only updating just the items(model) in the jtable and do not instantiate the jtable every time u click the button.